# My input is in the XML format that needs to be converted into a list structure in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to take an API call response and parse the XML data into list, but I am struggling with the multiple child/parent relationships.

My hope is to export a new XML file that would line up each job ID and tracking number, which I could then import into Excel.
Here is what I have so far
The source XML file looks like this:

```
<project>
   <name>October 2019</name>
   <jobs>
      <job>
      <id>5654206</id>
      <tracking>
         <mailPiece>
             <barCode>00270200802095682022</barCode>
             <address>Accounts Payable,1661 Knott Ave,La Mirada,CA,90638</address>
             <status>En Route</status>
             <dateTime>2019-10-12 00:04:21.0</dateTime>
             <statusLocation>PONTIAC,MI</statusLocation>
        </mailPiece>
     </tracking>...
Code:

    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
    
    tree = ET.parse('mailings.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root.tag)
    
    for x in root[1].findall('job'):
        id=x.find('id').text
        tracking=x.find('tracking').text
        print(root[1].tag,id,tracking)
```

The script currently returns the following:

jobs 5654206 None
jobs 5654203 None

Comment: Seems like you are parsing XML contents wrong. Could you please tell, what is your expected output.

Comment: Load a valid xml and share the expected output please.